# Mute command with 2 arguments (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: java, bukkit

For some reason I am having an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on line 41. I have been trying for at least an hour to figure out what's wrong with my code. I am trying to create a mute command, so the command should be: /mute [player] [enable/disable].

Your help is much apprechiated.

```
package me.parat26.cmds;

import me.parat26.admingui.MessageManager;
import me.parat26.admingui.SettingsManager;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class Mute implements CommandExecutor
{
    SettingsManager config = SettingsManager.getInstance();
    MessageManager send = MessageManager.getInstance();

    public static boolean chatDisabled = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
    {
        if ( sender.hasPermission((String) config.getConfig().get("permissions.mute")) )
        {
            if (args.length == 0)
            {
                send.message(sender, "Error", "Please provide enough arguments.");
            }

            if (args.length == 1)
            {
                Player offender = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                String s = sender.getName();

                if (offender == null)
                {
                    send.message(sender, "Error", "Player " + ChatColor.YELLOW + args[0] + ChatColor.WHITE + " could not be found.");
                    return true;
                }
                // Line 41
                if (args[0] != null && args[1] != null && offender != null && offender.isOnline())
                {
                    if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("enable"))
                    {
                        send.message(sender, "Yes", "Enabled...");
                    }
                    else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("disabled"))
                    {
                        send.message(sender, "Yes", "Disabled...");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    send.message(sender, "Error", "Please provide enough arguments.");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Thanos
are you sure that you are passing correct number of arguments?
Can you please try changing the line if(args.length ==1) to if(args.length ==2)

Comment: Sorry for that, I have added the line 41.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
if (args.length == 1)
  {
      /* ... */

      if (args[0] != null && args[1] != null &
      // Problem is here ----^
```

If `args.length` is `1`, you can't try to access `args[1]` because the array doesn't have one. That's why you get the exception.

Either the `args.length == 1` test is wrong, or you need not to use `args[1]` anywhere within that `if` block.

Comment: Thank you, seems like the problem is now solved! (And sorry for making you count the lines ;))....